# Как изменить сообщение самого первого коммита?

Tags: git

Есть репозиторий, в нём три последовательных коммита.

Как мне изменить сообщение изначального, первого коммита?

`git rebase -i HEAD~2` приводит к редактированию только двух последних.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень просто. Опустить конкретный коммит и добавить опцию `--root`:

```
git rebase -i --root
```

Так среди коммитов в запросе интерактивного ребейза окажется и самое начало.

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно!)